# Tic Tac Toe game v2

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, tic-tac-toe

I made the changes that were suggested to improve the program in [the previous version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274308/tic-tac-toe-in-python-with-oop/).
I would like to know if there is anything to improve in terms of handling object oriented programming, variable/method names, documentation, things that can be optimized, and so on. (Ignore the artificial intelligence part).

constants.py

```py
FIELD_X = "X"
FIELD_O = "O"
FIELD_EMPTY = " "
SPACER = "-" * 50
WAYS_TO_WIN = (
    # Rows.
    slice(0, 3),
    slice(3, 6),
    slice(6, 9),
    # Columns.
    slice(0, 7, 3),
    slice(1, 8, 3),
    slice(2, 9, 3),
    # Diagonals.
    slice(0, 9, 4),
    slice(2, 7, 2)
)
```

board.py

```py
from constants import FIELD_EMPTY, WAYS_TO_WIN
from itertools import chain


class Board: 
    def __init__(self):
        self._board = [" "] * 9
        
    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string with game board."""
        return "{}║{}║{}\n═╬═╬═\n{}║{}║{}\n═╬═╬═\n{}║{}║{}".format(*chain(self._board))

    @property
    def board(self):
        return self._board

    @board.setter
    def board(self, board):
        self._board = board
        
    def board_full(self):
        """Return True if every space on the board
        has been taken. Otherwise return False."""
        return FIELD_EMPTY not in self.board

    def check_win(self, board, letter):
        """Given a board and a player letter
        return True if that player has won."""
        return any(board[s] == [letter, letter, letter] for s in WAYS_TO_WIN)
```

tic_tac_toe.py

```py
from board import Board
from constants import FIELD_X, FIELD_O, FIELD_EMPTY, SPACER
from collections import deque
from copy import deepcopy
from random import choice


class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = Board()

    def select_letter(self):
        """Returns a tuple with the letter chosen by the player and the one chosen by the computer."""
        cpu_letter = None
        human_letter = None

        while True:
            human_letter = input("Choose your side: ").upper()

            if human_letter not in (FIELD_X, FIELD_O):
                print("You can only choose X or O.")
            else:
                break

        cpu_letter = FIELD_O if human_letter == FIELD_X else FIELD_X
        print(f"The computer has chosen to be {cpu_letter}.")
        print(f"You will be {human_letter}.")
        return human_letter, cpu_letter

    def human_goes_first(self):
        """Returns True if human chooses "yes" else False."""
        go_first = None
        while go_first not in ("yes", "no"):
            go_first = input(("Do you require the first move? (yes/no): ")).lower()
        return go_first == "yes"

    def get_random_move(self, moves):
        """Returns a valid move from the passed list on the passed board.
        Returns None if there is no valid move."""
        return choice(moves) if len(moves) != 0 else None

    def computer_move(self, human_letter, cpu_letter):
        """Given a board, the player's letter and the computer's
        letter, determine where to move to and the computer's
        letter is placed on the board in the determined position."""
        board_copy = deepcopy(self.board.board)
        corners = (0, 2, 6, 8)
        sides = (1, 3, 5, 7)
        # First, check if we can win in the next move.
        for i in range(8):
            if board_copy[i] == FIELD_EMPTY:
                board_copy[i] = cpu_letter
                if self.board.check_win(board_copy, cpu_letter):
                    self.board.board[i] = cpu_letter
                    return

        # Check if the player could win on their next move, and block them.
        for i in range(8):
            if board_copy[i] == FIELD_EMPTY:
                board_copy[i] = human_letter
                if self.board.check_win(board_copy, human_letter):
                    self.board.board[i] = cpu_letter
                    return

        # Try to take one of the corners, if they are free.
        move = self.get_random_move(corners)
        if move:
            self.board.board[move] = cpu_letter
            return

        # Try to take the center, if it's free.
        if self.board.board[4] == FIELD_EMPTY:
            self.board.board[4] = cpu_letter
            return

        # Move on one of the sides.
        move = self.get_random_move(sides)
        self.board.board[move] = cpu_letter

    def player_move(self, letter):
        """The player chooses the position on the
         board and the player's letter is placed
         on the board at the entered position."""
        while True:
            try:
                move = int(input(f"It's your turn {letter}. Enter a number [1-9]: ")) - 1
                if not 0 <= move <= 8:
                    print(f"The number entered is invalid. Enter a number between 1 and 9.\n\n{SPACER}\n")
                elif self.board.board[move] != FIELD_EMPTY:
                    print(f"This field is already occupied.\n\n{SPACER}\n")
                else:
                    self.board.board[move] = letter
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print(f"Enter a number!\n\n{SPACER}\n")

    def play(self):
        """The game stage."""
        print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!")
        human_letter, cpu_letter = self.select_letter()
        first_player = self.human_goes_first()
        letters = deque((human_letter, cpu_letter) if first_player else (cpu_letter, human_letter))
        players = deque(("Human", "Computer") if first_player else ("Computer", "Human"))
        print(f"\n{SPACER}")

        while not self.board.board_full():
            current_letter = letters[0]
            current_player = players[0]
            print(f"\nNow playing: {current_player} ({current_letter})")

            if current_letter == human_letter:
                self.player_move(human_letter)
            else:
                self.computer_move(human_letter, cpu_letter) 

            print(f"\n{self.board}\n\n{SPACER}")
            
            if self.board.check_win(self.board.board, current_letter):           
                print(f"\n{current_player} won!\nThanks for playing!")
                break

            letters.rotate()
            players.rotate()
        else:
            print("\nNobody won, it's a tie.")
```

main.py

```py
from tic_tac_toe import TicTacToe


def main():
    game = TicTacToe()
    game.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Updated code: https://github.com/xSyrax123/Tic-Tac-Toe-game/tree/main/tic_tac_toe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you see code repetition, consider writing a function**. In three
situations, you need to collect user input from a fixed menu of choices: X or
O; yes or no; and 1 through 9. Rather than implementing that behavior three
times, each slightly different, implement it once. The only tricky part is
converting the digits-as-strings to the needed integers.

```
def get_reply(prompt, choices, convert = None):
    # Prepare the conversion function.
    identity = lambda x: x
    convert = convert or identity

    # Return the first valid reply.
    choices_str = '/'.join(str(c) for c in choices)
    while True:
        reply = input(f'{prompt} ({choices_str}): ')
        try:
            val = convert(reply)
            if val in choices:
                return val
        except Exception:
            pass
        print('Invalid reply.')
```

**The Board's board property doesn't provide any utility**. At least none that
I can see. I would drop the property and just store a simple attribute. Also,
don't forget to use your `FIELD_EMPTY` constant.

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [FIELD_EMPTY] * 9
```

**The responsibilities of Board are leaking out into the rest of the program,
part 1**. In `player_move()` you worry about whether the player's choice is
`FIELD_EMPTY`. But that's not the job of TicTacToe -- at least not directly.
Better would be to implement a simple property of Board to return a collection
of the open spots. That change better aligns the OO responsibilities and it
ties in nicely with how we need to use `get_reply()`.

```
class Board:

    @property
    def open_spots(self):
        return [
            i + 1
            for i, cell in enumerate(self.board)
            if cell == FIELD_EMPTY
        ]
```

**Collections are often more powerful than discrete variables, part 1**.
One example is
`select_letter()`. Your current code defines separate variables for each
letter (`cpu_letter` and `human_letter`), asks for user input, and based on
that input does some logic to inform the user. The code is reasonable and not
difficult to follow; however, it's bulkier than necessary. A simple collection
(a list of 2 elements) eliminates the need to spawn a lot of variables and
shortens up the code:

```
def select_letter(self):
    letters = [FIELD_X, FIELD_O]
    if get_reply('Choose your side', letters) == FIELD_O:
        letters.reverse()
    print('You will be {}. The computer will be {}.'.format(*letters))
    return letters
```

**Collections are often more powerful than discrete variables, part 2**. I
would probably do something similar in `play()`: bundle the information in one
collection rather than creating lots of variables to be managed. If we stick
with your reasonable idea to use a deque, it might look like this:

```
def play(self):
    ...

    letters = self.select_letter()
    players = deque(zip(
        letters,
        ('Human', 'Computer'),
        (self.player_move, self.computer_move),
        (letters[0:1], letters),
    ))
    if not self.human_goes_first():
        players.rotate()

    ...

    while not self.board.board_full():
        letter, label, mover, move_args = players[0]
        ...
        players.rotate()
```

**Speaking of `play()`, while-else is a Python rarity**. I hardly ever see it
used in production Python code, because it's not as immediately intuitive as
the basic alternative: just breaking out of the loop and doing the normal
thing. Every ordinary English speaker understands "if else"; even experienced Python programmers scratch their heads over "while else" and its equally dubious sibling "for else".

**The responsibilities of Board are leaking out into the rest of the program,
part 2**. In `player_move()` and `computer_move()` you allow the TicTacToe
class to manipulate the internal data of the Board class. That's a violation of
strict OO principles. More concretely, it results in a bug. For example: play
X, go first, and enter moves 7, 5, 1. The `computer_move()` function rudely
overwrites the human's prior play on spot 7. Under a more strict OO approach,
TicTacToe would ask Board to place a letter on a spot, and the Board would
accept or reject this change. Here's one way to do that, plus an illustration
of how it would be used in `player_move()`. When you convert `computer_move()`
to use the new Board method, you'll see that an IllegalMove is raised if you play
the example described above. This is a good example of how a sensible amount of
OO-strictness can reveal bugs early (it's possible, of course, to take OO rules
to ridiculous extremes, but that's a topic for a different day).

```
class Board:

    def play(self, letter, spot):
        i = spot - 1
        if self.board[i] == FIELD_EMPTY:
            self.board[i] = letter
        else:
            raise IllegalMove(f'Spot {spot} is already occupied')

class IllegalMove(Exception):
    pass

class TicTacToe:

    def player_move(self, letter):
        move = get_reply(
            f"It's your turn {letter}. Enter a number",
            self.board.open_spots,
            convert = int,
        )
        self.board.play(letter, move)
```

**The responsibilities of Board are leaking out into the rest of the program, part 3**.
While you're fixing `computer_move()`, you should take
advantage of Board.open_spots. The reasoning is similar to the discussion
above: it's the job of Board (not TicTacToe) to keep track of which spots are
open. In a similar vein, I would probably make `WAYS_TO_WIN`, `CORNERS`, and
`SIDES` class-level constants in Board: all of them are simple facts about the
board, so Board should provide them. Similarly, if you revamp `computer_move()`
I suggest that you implement a method or property on Board to return basic
facts about the winning pathways: for example, some kind of data structure to describe the
status of the 8 ways-to-win. Every row/column/diagonal can be empty, deadlocked
(already containing both X and O), or be tilted in favor of X or O. A
move-making function should ask the Board to report that kind of information,
and the function should select its move accordingly. In my copy of the code, I
simplified `computer_move()` to make a random selection (because I was too lazy
to make the fixes and adjustments implied by the discussion above). In addition
to demonstrating my laziness, it illustrates the key principles of the model
I'm suggesting: (1) the Board provides Board-related facts, (2) the mover makes
a selection, and (3) the mover asks the Board to implement that selection.

```
class TicTacToe:

    def computer_move(self, cpu_letter):
        spot = choice(self.board.open_spots)
        self.board.play(cpu_letter, spot)
```

**You don't need itertools.chain**. `Board.__str__` will work fine without it.

**The Board.check_win method should not need its own data as an argument**. You
added the argument to facilitate the forward-looking logic in
`computer_move()`, but that's unnecessary. Just deep-copy the entire Board
instance.

**The Board.check_win method should not need a letter as an argument**. I continue to
think your life will be simpler if the method checks for any win rather than
just checking for a specific letter. Whether this change is worth the trouble
will depend on how you decide to handle `computer_move()`.

```
def check_win(self):
    for letter in [FIELD_X, FIELD_O]:
        victory = [letter, letter, letter]
        if any(self.board[s] == victory for s in WAYS_TO_WIN):
            return letter
    return None
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions, I have a little doubt. What are you doing here: convert = convert or identity? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Another doubt, would you recommend to put the tiles in a class of type enum?

Comment: @LucioMazzini You're welcome. (1) If `convert` is `None`, we assign the identity function to it. You could write it more explicitly as `convert = identity if convert is None else convert`, but the `x = a or b` idiom is a more compact way to handle that kind of situation. (2) The tiles meaning X and O? You could use an enum, although I don't see any big problems with your current approach regarding those constants.